# Custom classes in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

New to .NET Core I'm trying to make a custom class, that I can call from different controllers.

In the root of my project I've created a folder called Helpers. In that I've created *EncryptString.cs:*

```
namespace VPV.Helpers {
    public class EncryptString {
        public string Index(string val, string salt) {
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(val + salt);
            data = SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(data);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
        }
    }
}
```

But how do I call that from my controller?

I've tried something like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(Guid id, string password, string passwordCheck) {
    hashedPassword = new VPV.Helpers.EncryptString [...]
}
```

But I'm stuck from there.

Comment: I think you probably wanted that to be a static call. However the better approach would be to make that helper an injectable service, but not sure if you may consider that too advanced or overkill. I only suggested it as you indicated that it would be used by multiple controllers.

Comment: Given the `OnPostAsync` naming. is this a razor pages project?

Comment: I'd like to keep it as simple as possible. Is it possible to proceed the way I've started? IMO it can't be done much simpler than to call "new VPV.Helpers.EncryptString" from the controllers where I need it? Yes, it's Razor Pages.

Comment: Ok then while not the best of designs, make the method static, and call it where needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you probably wanted that to be a static call. However the better approach would be to make that helper an injectable service, but not sure if you may consider that too advanced or overkill.

I only suggested it as you indicated that it would be used by multiple controllers.

Now since you mentioned that you wanted to keep it simple and, while not the best of designs, make the method static,

```
namespace VPV.Helpers {    
    public static class Strings {    
        public string Encrypt(string val, string salt) {
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(val + salt);
            data = SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(data);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
        }
    }
}
```

and call it where needed.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(Guid id, string password, string passwordCheck) {
    //...

    var hashedPassword = new VPV.Helpers.Strings.Encrypt(password, salt);

    //...
}
```

You could also consider converting the helper to an extension method

```
namespace VPV.Helpers {    
    public static class Strings {    
        public string Encrypt(this string val, string salt) {
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(val + salt);
            data = SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(data);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
        }
    }
}
```

which would then mean that you can call it like

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(Guid id, string password, string passwordCheck) {
    //...

    var hashedPassword = password.Encrypt(salt);

    //...
}
```

Comment: Injectable service is the way to go - not because its a good approach, but because that's how ASP.Net core is built to work. If you do it any other way, you'll be fighting it constantly.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is the one better than the other?

Comment: @Mads they are basically the same. In the end it will be based on your preference

Comment: @Mads by making it an extension method you can use either one of the suggested syntax calls.

Comment: @gbjbaanb fighting it how? Reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2 injection seems fairly simple too, but what do I gain?

Comment: @Mads it doesn't matter, if you try to use 'normal' classes, you'll end up in a world where it would have been easier to make them service classes instead, as that's what the framework wants and expects. Static classes work, but only if they're simple, otherwise you'll be passing objects in methods as the framework constructs them.